# Convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ with $a_n=\cos(\pi \sqrt{n^2+n+1})$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let the series
 $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ with $a_n=\cos(\pi \sqrt{n^2+n+1})$. I read that this series is convergent. I see that the series is divergent by the nth term divergence test since $a_n$ does not go to zero as $n$ goes to infinity. I don't see how to show that this series converge, thank you for your help!

Comment: Note that $n$ is an integer.  How does the argument of $\cos$ behave asymptotically as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: A better question for the OP: where did you read that this series is convergent?  Could you provide a screenshot or a reference?

Comment: What is your definition of convergence? For $n$ large the terms flip between $-1$ and $1$ so the series might be Césaro summable.

Comment: Cesaro summability seems to be very likely

Comment: @nukeguy It is written in french : $a_n=\cos (n\pi +\pi/2+3\pi/8n+ O(1/n^2))=(-1)^{n+1}3\pi/8n+O(1/n^2)$

Comment: Where did you get the $\sqrt{n^2+n+1}$ from?

Comment: @nukeguy from a document of a french university. you can trust me I copied it exactly  as it is written.

Comment: @tired I checked with a small script. It appears to convegre to $\approx 0.4$.

Answer (score 8):

Note that
$$
\sqrt{n^2+n+1}=n\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}=n\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n^2}-\frac{1}{8n^2}+O(n^{-3})\right)\\=n+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{8n}+O(n^{-2}),
$$
so
$$
\cos(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n+1})=\cos(\pi n + \frac{1}{2}\pi+\frac{3\pi}{8n}+O(n^{-2}))\\=(-1)^{n+1}\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{8n}+O(n^{-2})\right) = (-1)^{n+1}\frac{3\pi}{8n}+O(n^{-2}).
$$
The leading-order term, $(-1)^{n+1}\frac{3\pi}{8n}$, is an alternating series whose terms decrease in absolute value with a limit of zero, so it is (conditionally) convergent.  The remainder term is absolutely convergent, since it is $O(n^{-2})$.  Therefore, the series with the combined terms converges.

Comment: Nice (+1) beat me by a minute!
It is fascinating how the subleading term enforces convergence due to the periodicity of sine.

Comment: A series whose terms are asymptotic to those of a convergent alternating series does not always converge; e.g. consider what happens if we add 1/(n ln n) to the terms of the alternating harmonic series.  The answer has been edited to repair this gap and then the editor gave +1 vote.

Comment: If your answer is independent. go ahead and submit it anyway. I do.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: Thank you, you're right that the *size* of the remainder term is also relevant.

Comment: @mjqxxxx:  You're welcome.  When using adymptotic analysis to prove that a series converges, calculate with sufficient accuracy so that the remainder-term series converges absolutely.  Then you are never wrong.